# Laravel custom response json

Tags: php, laravel

I have a useful response result that I have developed. But it doesn't return the result exactly as I want, so I can't get the "errorMessage" part.

Following my code :
`ResponseResult.php`

```
namespace App\Helpers;

class ResponseResult
{
    public static function generate(bool $success = true, $message = null, int $errorCode = 200) : object
    {
        if ($success) {
            return response()->json(['success' => $success, 'message' => $message], $errorCode);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['success' => $success, 'errorMessage' => $message, 'errorCode' => $errorCode],$errorCode);
        }
    }
}
```

`ExampleController`

```
$validate = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
        ]);

 if ($validate->fails()) {
     return ResponseResult::generate(false,$validate->messages(),ResponseCodes::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
 }
```

network output:

```
{success: false, errorMessage: {name: ["Name field is required."], lastname: ["lastname field is required."]},…}
errorCode: 404
errorMessage: {name: ["Name field is required."], lastname: ["lastname field is required."]}
success: false
```

I can't print any error when I try to get it as ErrorMessage. Can anyone help with this?

```
result.errorMessage.forEach(function (data) {
  $('#ajaxFails ul').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
});
```

Thank you advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you will `console.log(result)` you will most likely see that you return data is embed in to the `data` property. So the right way to display the error message will be:

```
result.data.errorMessage.forEach(function (data) {
  $('#ajaxFails ul').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
});
```

But again... it all depends how you build your data response.

Comment: I'm not sure if I need to call the special response I wrote somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

i am returning my validation error like this:

```
$validate = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
        ]);

 if ($validate->fails()) {
     $error = $validator->errors();
     return response()->json([
        'responseCode' => app('Illuminate\Http\Response')->status(),
        'error' => $error,
        'success' => false,
        'message'=>'',
    ]);
 }
```

Hope this will help you